# Disparar o jQuery usando o input hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

**FORM**

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='idRede'   value=" . $idRede . " /> ";
echo '  
        <label class="labelPequeno" for="idRegiao">Região</label> :
        <select name="idRegiao" id="idRegiao" class="inputTextMedio required">
            <option value="" selected>Escolha a Rede primeiro</option>
        </select> <br/>
```

Tenho o jQuery para popular a **Região**:

```
 $("#idRede").on("change", function () {                      

        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_buscas/buscarDadosRegioes.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  idRede: $("#idRede").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');
                $('#idRegiao').find('option').remove();

                if (result == null){
                    $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=>Sem Regiões</option>");
                } else {
                    $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=>Escolha a Região</option>");                      
                    result.forEach(function(option){
                        $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=" + option["idRegiao"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                    });
                }
            }

        });

    });
```

O problema é que a antes, `idRede` era um `SELECT` mas agora é um `input hidden`.

Alguma forma de disparar o jQuery usando o `input hidden`?

Grato a quem puder ajudar!

Comment: já tive um problema assim com os campos hidden, já tentou usando o `bind`? `$("#idRede").bind("change", function () {`

Comment: e como passo o valor no bins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só colocar a id `#idRede` no input hidden e disparar o evento `change` manualmente usando o método `.trigger()` do jQuery.

**Campo:**

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='idRede' id="idRede" value=" . $idRede . " /> ";
                                         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){

   $("#idRede").trigger("change");

});
```

Comment: rapas, falar pra você que funcionou!

Comment: Mt bom! valeu! :D

Comment: estanho tentei só assim             echo '<script>$("#idArea").trigger("change");</script>'; e não deu certo. Precisa mesma chamar o $(function(){?

Comment: O `$(function(){` espera que o DOM seja carregado caso vc esteja chamando antes do elemento.

Comment: pois é, por isso que estou confuso, pois coloquei após o elemento: echo '<script>$("#idRede").trigger("change");</script>';

Comment: Mas tb tem que ser após o `$("#idRede").on("change", function () {`

Comment: essa chamada $("#idRede").on("change", function () { fica no header da página, ou seja, bemmmmm lá no inicio da página e o ("#idRede")..change(); lá em baixo